# WPF-designer occurs appcrash devenv.exe when opening the xaml file in the visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

WPF-designer occurs appcrash devenv.exe when opening the xaml file in the visual studio 2010 environment.
OS : Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard(64bit) / CPU : i3 / RAM : 8GB 
Silverlight reinstall / VS2010 reinstall but problem is exist

This is error when opening the xaml file :

문제 서명:
  event name :  APPCRASH
  program name :    devenv.exe
  program version : 10.0.30319.1
  program timestamp :   4ba1fab3
  error module name :   unknown
  error module version :    0.0.0.0
  error module timestamp :  00000000
  error code :  c00000fd
  error offset :    0b6e0db9
  OS version :  6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Local ID : 1042